# Конкатенация строк в WinForms

Tags: winforms

```
private String CoordinatesToString(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        return "Координаты мыши: х=" + e.X.ToString() + "; y=" + e.Y.ToString();
    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //отображение текущих координат мыши в заголовке окна
        Text = CoordinatesToString(e);
    }

    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //определим какую кнопку мыши нажал пользователь
        String message = "";
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            message = "Вы нажали правую кнопку мыши.";
        }
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            message = "Вы нажали левую кнопку мыши.";
        }
        message += "\n" + CoordinatesToString(e);//ЧТО ПРОИСХОДИТ В ЭТОЙ СТРОКЕ

        //выведем сообщение в диалоговое окно
        String caption = "Клик мыши";
        MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
```

Comment: Что значит **"поясните синтаксис"**?

Comment: message += "\n" + CoordinatesToString(e);//что происходит здесь? Непонятен синтаксис

Comment: Отредактируйте, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос (чтобы тема была полезна другим участникам сообщества), а я отвечу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В строке `message += "\n" + CoordinatesToString(e);` к переменной `messge` "добавляется" в конец **"\n"**, что равносильно переносу строки, и результат выполнения функции `CoordinatesToString` с аргументом `e`. Т.е. функция вызывается, а к строке добавляется строка, которую возвращает данная функция, т.е. по сути это равносильно:

```
message += "\n" +  "Координаты мыши: х=" + e.X.ToString() + "; =" + e.Y.ToString();
```

Comment: это понятно. Непонятна запись: message +=   В данном случае смущает +

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо. Получается message = message + "\n"+ CoordinatesToString(e)// конкатенация строк с записью итогового значения в message. Верно?

Comment: Да, простым языком `+=` - прибавить, а `=` - перезаписать, а так как операция **+** приоритетнее, чем **+=** и **=**, то сначала выполнятся все **+**, а после уже увеличение/перезапись

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Происходит приращение переменной message значения, возвращаемого функцией CoordinatesToString(MouseEventArgs e), описанной в начале приведенного кода, с предварительной конкатанацией с переносом на новую строку "\n".
Функция CoordinatesToString, принимая событие мыши, возвращает строку типа "Координаты мыши: х=(координаты по горизонтали); у=(координаты по вертикали)"

Comment: message = CoordinatesToString(e);// а вот такая запись будет верной?

Comment: причем тут вот это +=

Comment: А почему нет? Верной, но результат будет другой. В первом случае, если переменная message уже содержала какое-то значение, то новая строка была бы добавлена к нему. А в данном случае, значение переменной message будет перезаписано. += дописать к строке, просто = - присвоить новое значение

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Proshka, [Оператор += (справочник по C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/sa7629ew.aspx)

Comment: @AlexKrass спасибо за ссылку. Именно в этом и состоял вопрос.